# A word to describe the action when a child make his/her hands motion like waving to say that something is not what he/she means

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't think of any word to describe the action when a child make his/her hand motion like waving to say that something is not what he/she means. 
Please, give me some suggestions. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you give a picture? Or link to video even better?

Comment: That is called *waving off*. It signals dismissal or recantation.

Comment: Is this an “erasing” motion in the air indicating, “No, No, you’ve got it wrong, erase that and try again.”

Comment: This sounds similar to the mediterranean gesture of the index finger extended and waved from side to side, meaning 'No'.

Comment: Well, it's more like Jim's description. I think the mediterranean gesture that Dan is talking about is best described with the verb 'wiggle one's finger'. I think 'gesticulate' that Mustafa suggested is the word I'm looking for. Thank you all. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**Gesticulate**:

> to make movements with your hands or arms, to express something or to emphasize what you are saying
>   <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gesticulate)</sub>

> She expresses herself better and does not *gesticulate* so violently.
>   <sub>[The Choice of Life](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/22411/22411-h/22411-h.htm)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In general, he *made a gesture of dissent* ([see dictionary definition and sentence](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dissent)).